# How can I know when a set of constraints were added to a specific table?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I am working with a table that has many constraints.

I am receiving errors while importing a clean data in the table.
I want to know at what time these constraints were added to the table so that I can have an idea whether it was after or before the bulk import in that table.

How can I find out when a constraint was added to a table (the date of creation of constraint)

I use PostgreSQL 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't record this information in the metadata.

If you have `log_statement = 'ddl'`, you might find the information in the log file.

Comment: is log_statement = 'ddl' inside the config file?

Comment: Yes, you set it in `postgresql.conf` or with `ALTER SYSTEM`.